# How to move to stateful page with Navigator

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to move to the next page with Navigator.
It works when I use `StatelessWidget` but fails with `StatefulWidget`.

Code that I am using:

```
     RaisedButton(
       onPressed: (){
           Navigator.of(context).push(SecondPage()));
       },
       child: Text('Next'),
```

Please let me know how to push `StatefulWidget` Page.

Thanks.

Comment: It should work with stateful widgets too. If you have converted the second page from stateless to stateful, try restarting your application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use the code sample as shared in the snippet below:

```
Navigator.push(
    context,
    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondRoute()),
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the reason why it does not work were.
Second page does not implemented properly returned null.

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Text('Page02'),
      ),
    );
  }
```